# Verifying the complex integral: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos{ax}}{1+x^4}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Verifying the integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{ax}}{1+x^4}dx$$

I started considering:
$$\cos{x}=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\implies \cos{ax}=\dfrac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}{2}?$$
So:
$$I=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{iax}}{1+x^4}dx+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-iax}}{1+x^4}dx=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{iax}}{1+x^4}dx+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \int_0^{-\infty}\dfrac{e^{iax}}{1+(-x)^4}d(-x)=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{iax}}{1+x^4}dx$$

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{e^a}{1+z^4}=\dfrac{e^a}{(z^2+i)(z^2-i)}$, with single poles:
$$z_{+1}=-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}i$$
$$z_{-1}=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}i$$
$$z_{+2}=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}i$$
$$z_{-2}=-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}i$$

Such that: $f(z)\cdot e^{iz}=\dfrac{e^{iaz}}{1+z^4}$

Then, i have seen (But dont know why) we can use the next relation:

$$2I=2\pi i \sum_{y>0}Res(f(z)\cdot e^{iz}, z_0)$$

Calculating the residues (Skipping the calculation):
$$Res(f(z)\cdot e^{iz}, z_{+1})=\lim_{z\to z_{+1}} (z-z_{+1})\cdot f(z)\cdot e^{iz}=$$

$$=\dfrac{e^{ia\cdot z_{+1}}}{2\sqrt2+2\sqrt2 i}$$

$$Res(f(z)\cdot e^{iz}, z_{+2})=\lim_{z\to z_{+2}} (z-z_{+2})\cdot f(z)\cdot e^{iz}=$$

$$=\dfrac{e^{ia\cdot z_{+2}}}{-2\sqrt2+2\sqrt2 i}$$

And finaly:

$$2I=2\pi i\big( \dfrac{e^{ia\cdot z_{+1}}}{2\sqrt2+2\sqrt2 i}+\dfrac{e^{ia\cdot z_{+2}}}{-2\sqrt2+2\sqrt2 i}   \big)$$

Comment: You can compare your result with that of Wolfram|Alpha, e.g. [this one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cos+%287x%29+%2F+%281+%2B+x^4%29+for+x%3D0..infinity). You didn't introduce $I$; it seems to stand for the integral you're seeking? And you seem to be thinking that $\mathrm e^r\cdot\mathrm e^s=\mathrm e^{r\cdot s}$ -- it isn't, it's $\mathrm e^{r+s}$; but it seems you're not actually using that factorization, so it shouldn't affect the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct :
$$I=\pi i\big( \dfrac{e^{ia\cdot z_{+1}}}{2\sqrt2+2\sqrt2 i}+\dfrac{e^{ia\cdot z_{+2}}}{-2\sqrt2+2\sqrt2 i}   \big)$$
Bringing back $z_{+1}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i)$ and $z_{+2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$ into it and after some elementary transformations :
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\exp\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a\right)\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$